# redux-toolkit extraReducers action.playload cant get deep value

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit

```
interface ListMakerResponse {
  result: number;
  detail: string;
  message: string;
  list: Maker[];
}

interface ListMakerRequest {
  dynamic: string;
}

type Maker = {
  makerId: string;
  makerName: string;
};

type OrganazationState = {
  status: "idle" | "loading" | "succeeded" | "failed";
  error: Error | null;
  response: ListMakerResponse;
};

const initialState: OrganazationState = {
  status: "idle",
  error: null,
  response: {} as ListMakerResponse,
};

export const postMakerList = createAsyncThunk(
  "list_maker",
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    const response = await http.usePost<ListMakerResponse, ListMakerRequest>(
      "http://localhost:8080/list_maker",
      {
        dynamic: "gravity",
      }
    );
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const OrganazationSlice = createSlice({
  name: "organazation",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder.addCase(postMakerList.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      const { message } = action.payload;

      console.log("successed", message);
      state.response = action.payload;
      state.status = "succeeded";
    });
    builder.addCase(postMakerList.rejected, (state, action) => {
      console.log("failed");
      state.status = "failed";
    });
  },
});

export const responseSelect = (state: RootState) => state.organazation.response;

export const messageSelect = createSelector(
  responseSelect,
  (res) => res.message
);

export default OrganazationSlice.reducer;
```

like the title the action.playload has the value but when I try to access the nested value in playload I get undefined. I want to get part of the response (like message or list) and show
on the html how can i do that.

I'm using useEffect to dispatch postMakerList

```
 const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  const response = useAppSelector(responseSelect);
  const message = useAppSelector(messageSelect);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(postMakerList());
  }, []);
```

the fact is when i use response it show up in the html but when i use message or response.message it
dont show up.

Comment: Try to add the code to sandbox and share the link

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the problem my code has no problem the problem is I use mockoon as
the stub and it return string instead of object.

Comment: If you provide valid JSON, Mockoon should return JSON and let you use the array/object. Do not hesitate to join our Discord if you need any specific help setting up your mocks. We will be glad to help!